# How can I add C/C++ and swig generated code to the same library using cmake

Tags: cmake, swig

The SWIG plugin to CMake is currently puzzling me. I want to build a single shared object that contains executable code compiled directly from C/C++ code as well as indirectly from input files to swig.

In my `CMakeLists.txt` file I therefore have

```
file (GLOB SOURCES ./src/ice/ice/*.c ./src/ice/ice/*.cpp)
add_library (ice SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories (ice PUBLIC ./bld/build/gen)
...
set_property(SOURCE ./src/ice/ice/ice_swig.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON) 
swig_add_library (ice LANGUAGE tcl SOURCES ./src/ice/ice/ice_swig.i ) 
...
```

During configuration, I get this error:

> CMake Error at /public/public64/packages/development/cmake-3.8.1/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:275
>   (add_library):
>           add_library cannot create target "ice" because another target with the
>           same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created in 
>           source directory "/home/steve/cmake_games/src/ice/ice".
>   See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
>           Call Stack (most recent call first): src/ice/ice/CMakeLists.txt:20 (swig_add_library)
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

It seems that both `add_libary` and `swig_add_library` are defining a target with the same name. This does not allow me to add both C/C++ "handcrafted" code and swig generated code to the same library. What is the correct way of using CMake to add SWIG generated C/C++ to the same library?

Comment: For one you should name one of the two libraries differently (`swig_add_library` uses `add_library` under the hood). Then, you can go on and set up a dependence relationship between those two libraries with [`add_dependecies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html). I'd suggest having one of the two libraries be static, as having a shared library that depends on another shared library is confusing and error prone.

Comment: Regretfully this is not possible because I need to be compatible to the currently used build system und source code. Code that uses the tcl "packages" shall not be forced to load different shared objects than using the old build system. On the other hand code that links against the pure C/C++ shared object shall not be forced to change its linker statements.

Comment: ok, so that I make sure that I understand; the end libraries should have the same name because of backwards compatibility requirements.

Comment: Ideally yes. A workaround could be that the library containing the tcl wrapper code will be called differently and I take care of this when generating the Tcl pkgIndex.

Comment: That's what I'd suggest; leave that to your packaging/installation later on. Otherwise, you still need to provide *different* names to the targets of the two commands and different output directories so that they don't overwrite each other (see [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) property). Now, that'll cause the name of the resulting libs to differ. To handle that, you can control the name with [`OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) property using `set_target_properties`.

Comment: Also, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48802601/edit) your question with those requirements, because it is not clear as is and "suppress" on the title doesn't have the meaning you're trying to convey.

Comment: Understood. I was somehow implying part of a possible solution instead of only describing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We solved this by creating a child library and linking it with the SWIG library:

```
file (GLOB SOURCES ./src/ice/ice/*.c ./src/ice/ice/*.cpp)
add_library (ice_baby SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories (ice_baby PUBLIC ./bld/build/gen)
...
set_property(SOURCE ./src/ice/ice/ice_swig.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON) 
swig_add_library (ice LANGUAGE tcl SOURCES ./src/ice/ice/ice_swig.i ) 
swig_link_libraries (ice ice_baby)
...
```

Comment: I see what you did there. Do you think you could do it under pressure?

Comment: Take a bow my friend. When stack becomes youtube comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new syntax of [`UseSWIG`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseSWIG.html)

first:

```
swig_add_library (ice_tcl
TYPE STATIC
LANGUAGE tcl
SOURCES ./src/ice/ice/ice_swig.i)
```

then try to add:

```
target_link_library(ice PRIVATE ${SWIG_MODULE_ice_tcl_REAL_NAME})
```

ps: not sure if the swig generated tcl file won't try to open the ice_tcl library directly...
In this case you'll need two libraries like here: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-swig